# WiFi icon keeps blinking, can't turn it on or off

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean

Can't connect to Wifi on my phone, because the ON/OFF slider is grayed out:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Also, the WiFi icon keeps blinking, and I can't turn it on/off. Kinda frustrating.

Android Jellybean.

Comment: Have you rebooted? Have you charged?

Comment: You can use the Android debug bridge to investigate: "adb shell" then "dmesg" and "logcat" will give you the kernel's and Android's logs.

Comment: I did reboot my phone, did a factory default reset, it still has the same error :/

Comment: How do I use the debug bridge? I'm kind of a n00b here lol

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by deleting `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`.
It will reset all your saved networks.
I have it rooted and deleted the file through a root explorer or you can remove it via ADB (`adb shell rm -r /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`. I'm not sure).

You may backup it before, then open with a text reader to see your saved passwords.

Answer (score 0):

By just getting back to date from 10-12-2015 to 07-12-2015, in my case to be precise, everything is back to normal, and here I am sharing my facts to help all those who are facing this ridiculous problem.

P.S. had been searching throughout the net for the solution and found some interesting details, would love to share for others (if they can be of any help).

Factory formatting/soft or hard resetting won't work, so as the phone rebooting will also be not effective. Setting back the clock (manually) worked like a charm for me (my mobile Lenovo Vibe X, carrier Vodafone). This problem arose, in my case, when I updated certain apps 5 or 6 OTA on Google Play Store (mainly Google inbuilt ones).

---

For other users who suffer the same problem as I came to read through their posts: when they updated their handsets (for any updates, irrespective of any app), their WiFi settings got disturbed causing the WiFi to lock while initialising, not allowing the user to switch On or OFF, just displaying the screen Wi-Fi turning on/Scanning/Starting/Searching/etc.

A common solution suggested by many (which even I was going to try ~ if above hadn't work) was to solve it by deleting `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`. It will reset all your saved networks. Have your phone rooted and delete the file through a root explorer or you can remove it via ADB (`adb shell rm -r /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`. I'm not sure). You may backup it before, then open it with a text reader to see your saved passwords.

On many forums, this was the common solution accepted as the only chance to get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a samsung Galaxy S5
I seemed to have fixed mine by going to settings, Internet, Advanced, Manage website data. Then clearing out all the saved webpages which i dont know why it saved in the first place
This is the first its happened to me But after a few times of flicking the wifi it seems to be working fully now
Hope this helps someone else 
<3

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, I cleared out the saved webpages in the 'internet' app and changed the date in 'time and date settings' to one week back. Restarted the phone and bingo! No more flashing wifi symbol on and off every couple of seconds! I had tried all the other stuff (restarting etc) apart from the rooting. This worked on a Galaxy Note 4, no rooting, no safe mode starts.I hope it works for others. I was sure this problem was draining the battery more than usual too? Thanks to everyone with all the suggestions above, especially 'aebbee'

Answer (score 0):

I've got a Samsung S5 and had the same issue which severely drained my battery!
None of the above worked for me. But I fixed it.

In the location settings it gives you the option to use Wifi or Bluetooth to increase accuracy - turn this off and voila.. : )

Hope this helps someone.